# Why String.format("%.2f", 10.0F) returns value 10,00 instead of 10.00?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, string.format

UPDATE: Removing "in Android 5.0" in the above question as I feel it has nothing to with the version but depends on the locale.

The usual output of the code below is **10.00**. But in Android 5.0 it returns value **10,00**.

```
 String value = String.format("%.2f", 10.0F);
 System.out.println("Value is "+value); //For Console Output
 Log.w("NumberClass.java","Value is "+value); //For Logcat Output
```

Is the functionality of

```
 String.format("%.2f", 10.0F);
```

is Changed in android lollipop? If So what is the solution for this strange behaviour?

**I need 10.00 as the output.**

Comment: It uses default locale. You should initialize the formatter with specific locale.

Comment: [for me 10,00 is a good ... 10.00 is bad ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc for `String.format()` says:

> Returns a localized formatted string, using the supplied format and
>   arguments, using the user's default locale.

So if you're French, a coma will be used, but if you're american, a dot will be used.

You may want to use `String.format (Locale locale, String format, Object... args)` (which is an overload of the function you are currently using) to get the desired behaviour. (see doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)). You can give it an initialized `Locale` to get the behaviour that you want. For more information on `Locale` check the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String value2 = String.format(getResources().getConfiguration().locale,"%.2f", 10.0F);
```